# How do I get list of photos displayed from urls using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I only know how to display one photo with url but how about a list of photos with different urls? And it will be better to also show the name of the photo under each photo
Thanks for any hints

Comment: there are many way to implement like collectionview,tableview but it depend on you which way you preferred

Answer (score 0):

You can use tableview with custom cell to show the list. For more specific help please share more information or you codebase.